# How to stop ignoring duplicate entries in "WHERE IN ()" query?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I'm trying to get a query that counts the specific macro and microingredients of a meal for a project. I have a `List<Long>` of ids that represent specific meals, and using that list, I want to calculate combined values of ingredients. The problem is that some of the meals are being duplicated (and that's OK), but when I pass the list to my SQL query, it ignores the duplicated IDs (for example, if list looks like {1,3,4,1,5} it will only count the ingredients of meal ID 1 once, and I need it to not ignore the second instance.

My query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT s.nazwa, SUM(ps.wartosc * (pwp.wartosc / 100)/pwp.liczba_porcji_posilku) as ilosc_skladnika, s.jednostka, s.grupa_skladnikow_odzywczych
FROM produkty_skladniki ps
JOIN posilki_produkty pwp USING (produkt_id)
JOIN skladniki s USING (skladnik_id)
WHERE pwp.posilek_id IN (LIST FROM JAVA HERE)
GROUP BY skladnik_id, s.nazwa, s.jednostka, s.grupa_skladnikow_odzywczych, s.skladnik_id 
ORDER BY s.kolejnosc
```

And my method that passes the list to

```java
public List<SimulatedMealInfo> checkNorms(List<Menu> menuList){
    //If there are records in DB remove them beforehand
    if(!simulatedMealInfoService.findAll().isEmpty()){
        simulatedMealInfoService.deleteAllCustom();
    }
    //Get the meal ID from each Menu class item
    List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Menu item : menuList){
        ids.add(item.getMeal().getMealId());
    }
    //Create list of objects returned by query
    List<Object[]> mealObjectView = mealService.checkIngredientsOverall(ids);
    //Create list of objects that will hold needed info
    List<SimulatedMealInfo> mealInfo = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Object[] mealSecond : mealObjectView){
        Double d = (Double) mealSecond[1];
        //Create new objects using info returned by the query
        SimulatedMealInfo simulatedMealInfo = new SimulatedMealInfo(null,mealSecond[0].toString(),
                String.format("%.3f",d/7), mealSecond[2].toString(), mealSecond[3].toString());
        mealInfo.add(simulatedMealInfo);
    }
    //save dump
    simulatedMealInfoService.saveAll(mealInfo);
    return mealInfo;
}
```

Comment: so the problem is here `WHERE pwp.posilek_id IN (LIST FROM JAVA HERE)` where the list value could be `{1,3,4,1,5}` ?

Comment: I've never seen the behavior you describe, could you share some data so we can play with this?

Comment: @FrankHeikens saddly can't provide actual data, best I can do is present example as screenshot of the  problem so:

For only if the list contains a single id all works fine (2 examples below for ids 218 and 219)

218:
[link]https://imgur.com/Y7ncwMn
219:
[link]https://imgur.com/DhcRlYu

Focus on the 2nd row - > the values there are 65,19 and 209.

For a list with both values (218, 219) value is 274 - a sum of both values
[link]https://imgur.com/gdIUNdq

However if a value occures more than once its 2nd and next occurances are ignored as shown here
[link]https://imgur.com/Lk8S8cP

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database you are using, there is a way to declare a temporary table with some values, make it in join instead of in().
Example in SQL server of a local table that can be joined:

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1), (3), (4), (1), (5)) AS TempTable(ColumnName)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can modify your Java code to include duplicated meal IDs:

```
public List<SimulatedMealInfo> checkNorms(List<Menu> menuList){
    //If there are records in DB remove them beforehand
    if(!simulatedMealInfoService.findAll().isEmpty()){
        simulatedMealInfoService.deleteAllCustom();
    }
    //Get the meal ID from each Menu class item and duplicate them based on frequency
    List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Menu item : menuList){
        long mealId = item.getMeal().getMealId();
        int frequency = Collections.frequency(ids, mealId);
        for (int i = 0; i < frequency; i++) {
            ids.add(mealId);
        }
    }
    //Create list of objects returned by query
    List<Object[]> mealObjectView = mealService.checkIngredientsOverall(ids);
    //Create list of objects that will hold needed info
    List<SimulatedMealInfo> mealInfo = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Object[] mealSecond : mealObjectView){
        Double d = (Double) mealSecond[1];
        //Create new objects using info returned by the query
        SimulatedMealInfo simulatedMealInfo = new SimulatedMealInfo(null,mealSecond[0].toString(),
                String.format("%.3f",d/7), mealSecond[2].toString(), mealSecond[3].toString());
        mealInfo.add(simulatedMealInfo);
    }
    //save dump
    simulatedMealInfoService.saveAll(mealInfo);
    return mealInfo;
}
```

SQL query that should count the ingredients of each meal ID for each occurrence in the list:

```
SELECT s.nazwa, 
       SUM(ps.wartosc * (pwp.wartosc / 100)/pwp.liczba_porcji_posilku) as ilosc_skladnika, 
       s.jednostka, 
       s.grupa_skladnikow_odzywczych
FROM produkty_skladniki ps
JOIN posilki_produkty pwp USING (produkt_id)
JOIN skladniki s USING (skladnik_id)
WHERE pwp.posilek_id IN (?)
GROUP BY pwp.posilek_id, skladnik_id, s.nazwa, s.jednostka, s.grupa_skladnikow_odzywczych, s.skladnik_id 
ORDER BY s.kolejnosc
```

GROUP BY clause now includes the pwp.posilek_id column, which ensures that the ingredients are counted separately for each occurrence of a meal ID in the input list. The ? placeholder represents a generic parameter that will be replaced with the list of meal IDs passed from Java.